# Change max votes allow per day to get more people voting on questions

Tags: feature-request

We wish people to vote more on questions.

Therefore why not change the

> “max 30 votes a day limit”

To

> “no more then 30 votes a day, of which
>   no more than 20 are for answers”

Or even

> No more than 5 votes on answers in a day if you have not also voted on a question

**Now please come up with something along these lines that will in fact work.**

Comment: witch -> which ;)

Comment: If it was to downvote questions, that's an idea to get behind.

Comment: There's far too much up-voting on questions as it is.

Comment: Meh! The electorate badge is bad enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already spend all my votes on questions and none on answers, because of the electorate badge.

No need for more incentive IMO

Comment: so should there be a limit on votes for questions os the likes of you don't advoid voting on answers just to get a badge?

Answer (score 10):

Badges are a gentle push to encourage behavior.

This method you mention isn't a push, it's a shove out of a plane with no reserve chute.

We cannot dictate what people vote on; and putting barriers up only pisses people off.

If people want something voluntary (badges) then they conduct a voluntary action (voting for questions and answers).

Comment: I am getting warning that i have left 3 votes. So I shouldn't vote now?

Comment: OK I understood I can vote in INDIA after `UTC +5.5` that is morning 4:30 am. Am I correct?